# Glassfish loading application - getting 404

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I've used glassfish for about a year now. The last 6 months my webapp have been running fine, but now I needed to make a change.

I the made the change, and pushed the application to the server, using glassfish tools in eclipse. Though now I can't access my webapp.

I checked my glassfish-web.xml at the context-root was the same as before.
I've tried manually changing the url in glassfish administration, but it's the same thing.

The logs shows that the app is loaded:

```
[2017-02-24T11:43:16.242+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1487932977205] [timeMillis: 1487932996242] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [DSLTest4Web] at [/DSLTest]]]

[2017-02-24T11:43:16.310+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00022] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1487932977205] [timeMillis: 1487932996310] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application DSLTest4Web done in 16,746 ms]]
```

Though when I access http://my-ip-addr/DSLTest I get a 404.

What the heck is happening?

Comment: Open domain admin console in browser and check deployed application location.

Comment: @Artem: ${com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI}/applications/DSLTest4Web/
So it is the right place :(